# How to time the user-data script runtime on instance creation?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I've configured a Stack at AWS CloudFormation which creates an AutoScaling Group and starts a few servers.

The member servers are running a user-data script (#!/bin/sh) the first time they are up.

I would like to time the user-data process.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty option would just be to grab current epoch time at the beginning of your script, grab epoch time at the end of the script, calculate the difference in the two and save it to a file that you can look at.

You could get more complex than that if this is something that is needed long term, but if not, this should work.